# Substring is slow with while loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

One of my table column stores ~650,000 characters (each value of the column contains entire table). I know its bad design however, Client will not be able to change it.

I am tasked to convert the column into multiple columns.
I chose to use dbo.DelimitedSplit8K [function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Unfortunately, it can only handle 8k characters at max.

So I decided to split the column into 81 8k batches using while loop and store the same in a variable table (temp or normal table made no improvement)

```
    DECLARE @tab1 table   ( serialnumber int, etext nvarchar(1000))
declare @scriptquan int = (select MAX(len (errortext)/8000) from mytable)


DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @A bigint = 1
DECLARE @B bigint = 8000
SET @Counter=1
WHILE ( @Counter <= @scriptquan + 1)
BEGIN
    insert into @tab1 select ItemNumber, Item from dbo.mytable cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(substring(errortext, @A, @B), CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) 

    SET @A = @A + 8000
    SET @B = @B + 8000
    
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

This followed by using below code

```
declare @tab2 table (Item nvarchar(max),itemnumber int, Colseq varchar(10)) -- declare table variable

;with cte as (
select [etext] ,ItemNumber, Item from @tab1 -- insert table name
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(etext,'    ')) -- insert table columns name that contains text

insert into @tab2 Select Item,itemnumber, 'a'+ cast  (ItemNumber as varchar) colseq
from cte  -- insert values to table variable

;WITH Tbl(item,  colseq) AS(
    select item, colseq from @tab2
),
CteRn AS(
    SELECT item, colseq,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY colseq ORDER BY colseq)
    FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
   a1 Time,a2 Number,a3 Type,a4 Remarks
FROM CteRn r
PIVOT(
    MAX(item)
    FOR colseq IN(a1,a2,a3,a4)
)p
    
    where a3 = 'error'
```

gives the desired output. However, just the loop takes 15 minutes to complete and overall query completes by 27 minutes. Is there any way I can make it faster? Total row count in my table is 2. So I don't think Index can help.

Client uses Azure SQL Database so I can't choose PowerShell or Python to accomplish this either.

Please let me know if more information is needed. I tried my best to mention everything I could.

Comment: *"each cell contains entire table"* Table's don't have "cells", it's not a Spreadsheet, they have columns and rows. I assume by "cell" you mean a value in a specific column and row. If so, the question begs *why* are you storing an entire table's worth of data in a single column in a single row? Fix your design.

Comment: Here is comparison of all variants to split the string: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Most likely if you pick a method that works on `nvarchar(max)` directly it will be much faster. Also see this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/splitting-strings-sql-server-2016-rescue/

Comment: Yes, by Cell I meant value of column and row. Thank you for correcting me. I agree with you on this, I did suggest the same however, Client didn't want to change the design for some reason.

Comment: *"Client didn't want to change the design for some reason."* Then time to force them; a client should not be making such disastrous design choices. They hire experts for a reason and they should *not* be anywhere near the decision making for the back end design. A system like this will be impossible to maintain, and will have **no** data validation (such as data types, constraints, foreign keys); it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Larnu, I agree. I should try to convince them again.

Comment: I always dislike that article from Bertrand, @VladimirBaranov, as although he mentions that Jeff's function has "minor changes" he **doesn't** mention how dramatically they affects performance; putting the function in poor light when it is far faster if you don't ruin it in the first place.

Comment: Formally, the code, as written, is O(N^2) and this is a primary driver of the poor performance.  Using one of the approaches from the sqlperformance article would generally be better - the table-of-numbers approach + join model, for example, is O(N) instead and should perform better.  (use whichever model you want that is algorithmically reasonable)

Comment: @Larnu, my point was to pick a method that does not require breaking the long text into 8K chunks. That article describes several methods, so OP can try all of them and compare their performance on his system.

Comment: I don't disagree on that, @VladimirBaranov , it's just that I know how much work was put into that function (and the latter `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`) and it always disappointing to see how poorly it's reflected in the article.